# Enabling dataBinding in build file makes transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug task fail

Tags: android, gradle

I am encountering a very strange error. For some reason, whenever I try to enable data binding within my build file the `transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug` task fails with this exception:

`org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.`

I can't quite figure out how these two things are connected. Here is my build file, I literally just created a new project with an empty activity and tried to enable data binding.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.shank.dbtest"
        minSdkVersion 28
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation"org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0-beta01'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.1.0-alpha05'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.0-alpha4'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0-alpha4'
}
```

gradle.properties file:

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1g
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
kotlin.code.style=official
```

Removing `dataBinding { enabled = true }` makes everything work fine. Enabling multidex does not have an effect. Removing the `=` also does nothing. The project is using gradle version 4.10.1 (the default when creating a new project in android studio). I'm also using Windows 10 (unfortunately), if that matters.

Anyone have any ideas?

**edit:**

gradle-wrapper.properties

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.10.1-all.zip
```

root build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.31'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: please also post your "gradle-wrapper.properties" and "project level" gradle

Comment: I added them to the main post 

Comment: change below lines in respective files:
"distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.1.1-all.zip"
"classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.2'"

Comment: updating did the trick! I did try updating the gradle version but not the build tools version. curious as to why android studio doesn't generate a project with the latest stable versions! thanks a lot :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update your distributionUrl in gradle-wrapper.properties as below:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.1.1-all.zip
```

And update tools.build:gradle in project level gradle

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.2'
```